# Bootstrap Column img background scaling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, image-scaling

I am having problems with my Bootstrap code at http://goo.gl/ARUJz9.

In the top of the body is a container:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12" id="banner-hdr"> 
     /div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#banner-hdr {
    height: 405px;
    background-image: url("../images/banner-bg.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This has a CSS background-image that will not scale with the site when viewed on mobile or tablets. If I use a straight img tag and then add responsive, it still does not work and the image does not fill the entire banner block.

How can I write this so that it will scale properly with smaller screens?

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing else going on for the header img, I would actually put a separate  within the div and set width:100% like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12"> 
        <img src="your picture" style="width:100%;">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way the header image will enlarge / shrink within its dimension.

Comment: Or you can set up breakpoints to toggle between larger/smaller images. I usually do this because sometimes the texts in the banner are too small for mobile devices to see.

Comment: Nope, tried that and it does not work. The image stretches the width but not the height.